# Non Numeric Value in php 7.3

Tags: php

I am doing calculation where

```
<?php 
echo (round($a+$l+$r+$tax+$mcd+$tcs+$fst));
?>
```

$a is price from database, and rest all value are calculated on basis of $a
getting Non Numeric Value errir
tried

```
<?php 
echo (int(round($a+$l+$r+$tax+$mcd+$tcs+$fst)));
?>
```

but is not working and white page is coming
can any one advise on same. thanks

Comment: Try using `var_dump()` on each variable and checking what they actually contain

Comment: is `$a` an Integer or a Float? You should make sure that each of those values is an integer or a float before trying to round them, depending on the desired result. as suggested below, try to `var_dump($each_var);` each of those variables BEFORE you round them, an post the output here, if you still do not have the solution.

Comment: E:\wamp64\www\28march2020\components\com_newcar\views\product\tmpl\default.php:63:string '438500' (length=6)
E:\wamp64\www\28march2020\components\com_newcar\views\product\tmpl\default.php:83:float 6210
E:\wamp64\www\28march2020\components\com_newcar\views\product\tmpl\default.php:304:float 19153
E:\wamp64\www\28march2020\components\com_newcar\views\product\tmpl\default.php:363:int 4000

( ! ) Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in E:\wamp64\www\28march2020\components\com_newcar\views\product\tmpl\default.php on line 376

Comment: @NigelRen Ron - added same, pl guide

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to cast each variable. To be sure try to use `var_dump()`. Maybe databases return you String and not a numeric value

Comment: Can you please complete the idea?

Comment: E:\wamp64\www\28march2020\components\com_newcar\views\product\tmpl\default.php:63:string '438500' (length=6)
E:\wamp64\www\28march2020\components\com_newcar\views\product\tmpl\default.php:83:float 6210
E:\wamp64\www\28march2020\components\com_newcar\views\product\tmpl\default.php:304:float 19153
E:\wamp64\www\28march2020\components\com_newcar\views\product\tmpl\default.php:363:int 4000

( ! ) Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in E:\wamp64\www\28march2020\components\com_newcar\views\product\tmpl\default.php on line 376